# Angular 2 @input data not properly binding

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

### Parent module:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedModule} from "app/shared/shared.module.ts";

import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';
import {UserinfoComponent} from './userinfo.component';
import {SearchComponent} from './search.component';
import {DropdownComponent, DropdownValue} from '../../forms/dropdown.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      HeaderComponent,
      UserinfoComponent,
      SearchComponent,
      DropdownComponent,
    ],
    imports     : [SharedModule],
    exports     : [HeaderComponent],
})

export class HeaderModule {
  items: DropdownValue[] = [
    {value: '1', label: 'test 1'},
    {value: '2', label: 'test 2'}
  ];
}
```

### Module html:

```
<div class="navbar dark-bg remove-bottom-margin flex-container">
    <search></search>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <dropdown [items] = "items"></dropdown>
    </div>
    <userinfo></userinfo>
</div>
```

### Component:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

export class DropdownValue {
  value: string;
  label: string;

  constructor(value: string, label: string) {
    this.value = value;
    this.label = label;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'dropdown',
  template:  `
    <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue.value" (change)="onChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]=item.value>{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>
  `,
})

export class DropdownComponent {
  selectedValue: DropdownValue = new DropdownValue('2', '');

  @Input()
  items: DropdownValue[];

  @Input()
  value: string[];

  @Output()
  valueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  onChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    this.valueChange.emit(event.target.value);
  }
}
```

If i set the test data in the component and remove data binding - it works.
I even tried something simple like `@input items: string` and set it as plain text in template. Still undefined.

What am i missing - i looked at examples and can't see anything different.
Do you need to import something specific in module for the data bind to work?

Comment: What exactly is not working? `@Input()`s values are not yet available in `constructor` only in `ngOnInit`

Comment: I also take it that markup is in a component template? It could just be something I don't know, but I've never seen inputs and such used in a module. Components are where I always use them. The way you've got it laid out in the OP, it looks like you're doing it all in the module.

Comment: The binded value is undefined.
If i initialise the Items in component with some values, they also get overwritten with undefined.

Comment: Updated to full code.

Comment: Again, you mean component html (not module)? Something else: you export what appears to be a service directly from a module. If you intend this to be used as a service, you need to "provide" it, then inject it into your component and use it that way (as a service). At least, that's how I always get the job done.

Comment: Yeah I whipped up a quick sample, and creating an "ItemsService", importing that into the HeaerModule, and "providing" it, such that it could be injected into the dropdown component, worked. Whatever other fix may come up, that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like i actually had to set the value for databind in `import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';` itself and not the module that imported it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some important modules that might be shared with other imports such as

```
import {SharedModule} from "./app/shared/shared.module.ts";
```

You can see the [<kbd>demo</kbd>](https://plnkr.co/edit/RUXqLi2b9pLWuRjxVwPM?p=preview) for the `dropdown` component.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly U need to add :

`items: DropdownValue[] = [
    {value: '1', label: 'test 1'},
    {value: '2', label: 'test 2'}
  ];`

In **another component for eg:xyz** and import it in your module.
Than,

`<dropdown [items] = "items"></dropdown>`

here [items]... Must be target property name that you mentioned with @Input in your component class and **="items"** should be property name which u mention in xyz component class...